# How do you override self?

Tags: php, oop, visibility

I want to build class that implement a lot of methods based on it's id,
so I want to have one class parent that implement the methods!
and when i want to use this class I will extend it and just override the id variable :

```
 class parent
    {
       $id = "parent";
       private __construct()
       { 
       }

       public static function create_instance()
       {
          $instance = new self();
          return $instance;
       }

       public static function print_id()
       {
          echo $this->id;
       }




    }

class child extend parent
{
   $id = "child";

}

$instance = child::create_instance();
$instance->print_id();
```

the result will be "parent", but I want the result to be child ?
How to do that ?

**EDIT** : I also tried this and got parent instead of child:

```
class parent1 {
    private $id = "parent";
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public static function create_instance() {
        $instance = new static ();
        return $instance;
    }
    public function print_id() {
        echo $this->id;
    }
}
class child extends parent1 {
    private $id = "child";
}

$instance = child::create_instance ();
$instance->print_id ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the visibility of `$id` is private whereas it should be protected because `print_id()` is only defined on the parent; as such it can only reach its own `$id`.

```
class parent1 {
    protected $id = "parent";
    // ...
}

class child extends parent1 {
    protected $id = "child";
}
```

The alternative is, of course, to override `print_id()` in the child class.

Answer (score 2):

Currently when you call create_instance method on child class as a result instance of parent class is created not child class as you expect.

Use late static binding in parent class "create_instance" method:

```
public static function create_instance()
{
    $instance = new static();
    return $instance;
}
```

More details http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php